# ToolBoxBitmap Attribute does not work in my component

Tags: c#, attributes, components, embedded-resource

I have a Windows Form application. I've added a class to my project named MyLibrary.cs and I inherited this class of System.ComponentModel.Component and I've also added a bitmap image with its build action set to EmbeddedResource to my resources folder, but when I write the code below and build the project my customized icon does not change when I want to drag and drop my component to my Form. Would you please help me?

I've checked a lot of links like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.toolboxbitmapattribute.aspx and [How to find the elusive ToolboxBitmap icon](https://web.archive.org/web/20120804065638/http://www.bobpowell.net/toolboxbitmap.htm) but none of them worked for me!

Here is my code:

MyLibrary.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

internal class resfinder
{
}
 
namespace MyForm
{
  
    [System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmap(typeof(resfinder),"MyForm.Bitmap1.bmp")]
     public class MyLibrary:System.ComponentModel.Component 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't include the namespace name in the string, that's what the first argument is for.  So just "Bitmap1.bmp".  Double-check the resource name with ildasm, find the .mresource in the manifest.

Comment: I did it ,but it didn't work!would you please give me a new instruction to do this?an instruction to change the icon of my component.I really appreciate your care Mr. Hans Passant .

Answer (score 0):

You should look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-provide-a-toolbox-bitmap-for-a-control) it says:

1. The bitmap must be 16x16
2. If you specify both a Type and a string, the control searches for an image resource with the name specified by the string parameter in the assembly containing the type specified by the Type parameter

So make sure your bitmap is located in the same assembly as "resfinder" and also put make sure in properties under build actions it is set as an Embedded Resource